# UWP unable to Upload the App to windows store as getting Supported API Error

Tags: xamarin, uwp

Using Private nuget dll packages, where facing an issue for windows store release, as we are using the local references for the below packages.

Supported APIs
Error Found: The supported APIs test detected the following errors:
API __std_type_info_destroy_list in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. custom_sqlite3.dll calls this API.
API _except_handler4_common in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. custom_sqlite3.dll calls this API.
API memcpy in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. custom_sqlite3.dll calls this API.
API memmove in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. custom_sqlite3.dll calls this API.
API memset in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. custom_sqlite3.dll calls this API.
Impact if not fixed: Using an API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Microsoft Store apps violates the Microsoft Store certification requirements.
How to fix: Review the error messages to identify the API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Microsoft Store apps. Please note, apps that are built in a debug configuration or without .NET Native enabled (where applicable) can fail this test as these environments may pull in unsupported APIs. Retest your app in a release configuration, and with .NET Native enabled if applicable. See the link below for more information

Can someone help me on this. Thanks

Comment: "How to fix: Review the error messages to identify the API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Microsoft Store apps."

Comment: The reason is that you used many APIs that are not supported by Microsoft Store in **custom_sqlite3.dll**. As Jason said, you could check these api in the custom_sqlite3.dll to see whether uwp supports them. If there is an unsupported API, you could replace it with other supported api. Or you could use another dll to instead the custom_sqlite3.dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure not to have the other dll than NuGet package, I think somewhere holding the other library exists, delete them and try to run through the Microsoft certificate test kit.

Please approve as the answer if this resolves your issue.